# Is the differentiation correct in pytorch tutorial?

Tags: pytorch

I'm going through https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-autograd-tutorial-py and noticed an equation I couldn't understand. For the below equation for the tutorial,

[image]

Isn't do/dx = 6 (xi+2). How is it 3/2(xi+2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `1/4` term in front of the summation. So you get `6/4(xi + 2) = 3/2(xi + 2)`.

Comment: a followup question. If we differentiate $ \dfrac{1}{4}\Sigma\hspace{.1cm} 3 (x_i+2)^2 $ wouldn't it be <\dfrac{3}{2}\Sigma\hspace{.1cm} (x_i+2)>. Where did the sigma go?

Comment: It's a derivative with respect to x_i. So the other x_j, j != i become 0.